# Using PointCloud2 data (getting x,y points) in Python

Tags: python, pcl, pcl-conversions, pointcloud, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a Python ROS node, I've subscribed to a sensor_msgs/LaserScan topic, converted them to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages, and am trying to extract X, Y (and Z) point coordinates. The transformation from LaserScan to PointCloud2 uses the LaserProjection class of laser_geometry. What is the data format of sensor_msgs/LaserScan.data? From the documentation and other questions, it's a binary format usually converted in C++ with the pcl_ros or pcl_conversions packages (eg http://answers.ros.org/question/10947/reading-float-from-float32-data-from-kinect-pointcloud2/), but I'm working in Python.

This is my code:

```
import rospy, math, random
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from laser_geometry import LaserProjection
```

...

```
class Lidar():
def __init__(self, scan_topic="/robot_0/base_scan"):
    self.scan_sub = rospy.Subscriber(scan_topic, LaserScan, self.on_scan)
    self.laser_projector = LaserProjection()

def on_scan(self, scan):
    print scan
    rospy.loginfo("Got scan, projecting")
    cloud = self.laser_projector.projectLaser(scan)
    print cloud
    rospy.loginfo("Printed cloud")
```

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202787/using-pointcloud2-data-(getting-x,y-points)-in-python/) by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my solution:

```
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
```

...

```
def on_scan(self, scan):
    rospy.loginfo("Got scan, projecting")
    cloud = self.laser_projector.projectLaser(scan)
    gen = pc2.read_points(cloud, skip_nans=True, field_names=("x", "y", "z"))
    self.xyz_generator = gen
```

The source/documentation for point_cloud2.py is http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/point__cloud2_8py_source.html, which describes the read_points method to parse a PointCloud2. From that method source, the format of PointCloud2.data seems to be a series of fields (x, y, z, intensity, index) packed with the struct library. The deserialization in that file is done by:

```
fmt = _get_struct_fmt(cloud.is_bigendian, cloud.fields, field_names)
width, height, point_step, row_step, data, isnan = cloud.width, cloud.height, cloud.point_step, cloud.row_step, cloud.data, math.isnan
unpack_from = struct.Struct(fmt).unpack_from
```

---

Originally posted by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) with karma: 165 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michaeljaison](https://answers.ros.org/users/27231/michaeljaison/) on 2016-06-20**:
How can you build an organized pointcloud in python-pcl?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-07-27**:
sincerely the deserialization you wrote doesn't make any sense to me. Can you elaborate? And where does _get_struct_fmt come from?

**Comment by [lr101095](https://answers.ros.org/users/34104/lr101095/) on 2018-05-09**:
@Mehdi. Ajay is referring to this (see line 76):
http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/point__cloud2_8py_source.html#l00060

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above mentioned method works fine, but I implemented following as it was easy to access points that way

```
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2

...
  
for p in pc2.read_points(point_cloud, field_names = ("x", "y", "z"), skip_nans=True):
     print " x : %f  y: %f  z: %f" %(p[0],p[1],p[2])
```

---

Originally posted by [wallE](https://answers.ros.org/users/26579/walle/) with karma: 51 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taiping.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/26425/taiping.z/) on 2018-10-04**:
Hi! Very practical implementation!
While occasionally, an error is reported. Any advices?

```
    *assert isinstance(cloud, roslib.message.Message) and cloud._type == 'sensor_msgs/PointCloud2', 'cloud is not a sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud2'
AssertionError: cloud is not a sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud2*
```

**Comment by [Atharva Mete](https://answers.ros.org/users/57504/atharva-mete/) on 2020-08-08**:
Hey, thanks your soln worked. Now I wanna know how to get corresponding pixel values?

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-04**:
@lucasw
hi,
the x,y,z are indicative of what? distance?  if i want to extract the distance from an object to the lidar, what should i do? is there any relation between the code that you provided and my question?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-08-04**:
If you know what points are on the object you care about, then the xyz values are very likely distance in meters to the origin of the lidar in it's frame- if the lidar we're tilted you would want to account for that

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-05**:
thanks @lucasw,
now the problem is that i donot know how to filter out the environment points, and just keep points related to the object!
do you have any idea about this part? how can i access to the points of the object?

and one more question about the direction of x,y,z. Is x forward, y on the right side, and z upward?

**Comment by [abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/128461/abbas/) on 2022-12-21**:
Hi @Delbina , were you able to extract only a segment of points from lidar pointcloud2 data. I am also trying to do same but cant find any suitable python package to do it.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-12-22**:
@abbas
I used voxel grid filtering (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/VoxelGrid%20filtering)